# Find an example of two sets A,B such that sup(A∩B) < min{supA,supB}.

Tags: real-analysis

Find an example of two sets A,B such that sup(A∩B) < min{supA,supB}.
We have A,B two nonempty subsets of R bounded above and below and such that A∩B != ∅.

Comment: $A=\{0,1\}$, $B=\{0,2\}$

Comment: 1 is not smaller than 1

Comment: @Kevin 1 is not in $A \cap B$.

Comment: In my example $A\cap B=\{0\}$.

Comment: @EricTressler How so? 1 is in {0, 1} and {0,2}

Comment: @lulu oh okay you meant the integers 0 and 1

Comment: To be clear:  both of my sets have only two elements. $A$ has only the elements $0$ and $1$.  $B$ has only the elements $0$ and $2$.

Comment: @lulu when is the inf equal the sup?

Comment: Sorry, in what context?

Comment: @lulu in any subset of R, when is the supremum equal to the inf?

Comment: Only for sets of one element.  If there are two elements $x<y$ then inf$≤x<y≤$sup

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Two copies of $\Bbb R$, one showing the set $A$, the other showing the set $B$:

```
                ---[aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]--------------------  
                ---[bbbbbbbbbbb]--------------------[bbbbbbbb]--
```